# Asterisk server warning "Unexpected control subclass"

Tags: linux, asterisk, server-crashes

I am not sure why, but our asterisk server keeps having loads of agents (15) on status ready and calls waiting for them, it seems to be griving us this error in our event log.

```
WARNING[7159] file.c: Unexpected control subclass '-1'
```

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://asterisk.inmte.com/viewtopic.php?t=14085) on the asterisk forums seems to say you can safely ignore it:

> You can safely ignore it. If you'd like to post a note to 
>   issues.asterisk.org, we can make it go away.
>
> Asterisk uses "control frames" as an internal messaging mechanism for 
>   certain types of signaling between channels. A "control subclass" is a
>   type of control message. An example of a subclass would be RINGING to 
>   indicate that the far end has sent us a message to say that they are 
>   ringing. A subclass of -1 basically means "stop whatever I told you 
>   last". If the last message was RINGING, a -1 means to stop that
>   indication.

Comment: ...which, by the way, was on the first page of results of a Google search for "file.c Unexpected control subclass".